# Regex for Rewriting Old URL in .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm not sure what the rewrite rule in my .htaccess needs to look like. My goal is to support old URL's that have parameters in them and convert them to the new URL.

Old URL

```
http://site1.domain.com/product.php?ID=12357/$10-gift-certificate
```

New URL

```
http://site1.domain.com/item/12357/$10-gift-certificate
```

The URL has various variables in it:

1. Subdomain (site1)
2. Item/Product ID (12357)
3. Description ($10-gift-certificate)

So put another way, the architecture of the updated url looks like this:

```
http://[subdomain].domain.com/item/[ID]/[description]
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: often people see these as backwards, I'm dyslexic so it looks normal to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /product\.php\?id=([^/]+)/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ item/%1/%2? [NE,NC,R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1/$2 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supporting the old one you really are supporting the new ones like this

```
 RewriteRule  /?category/([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Where your new url would be ( what the user sees )

```
yoursite.com/category/1
```

Which would map to  ( what the server sees )

```
index.php?category=$1
```

Old urls would work fine, as such.  The user ( end client ) would see only the url you have links for on your webisite ( the new format I assume ), And because these are not redirects the url will not change in the browser.

So in your example

```
 http://[subdomain].domain.com/item/[ID]/[description]
```

You'd want something like this

```
RewriteRule  /?item/([\d]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?ID=$1&description=$2 [L,QSA]
```

So this would be

INPUT

```
 http://site1.domain.com/item/12357/$10-gift-certificate
```

OUTPUT

```
 http://site1.domain.com/product.php?ID=12357&description=$10-gift-certificate
```

-note- that the browser will not `[R]` redirect so the url will not change to output only the server sees it this way.

unless `ID=12357/$10-gift-certificate` is really what you mean for the old url and I don't know what [subdomain] maps to.  Which in that case you would want this.

```
 RewriteRule /?item/(.+?)/?$ product.php?ID=$1
```

Which given the same input above would output

```
 http://site1.domain.com/product.php?ID=12357/$10-gift-certificate
```

So you see that the client sees the new url, but the server sees the old one.  Which is why I said most people look at this backwards, in the beginning.

Anyway, here is a site to test url rules on

http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

I am sure there are other sites out there too.

Comment: While I'm sure your solution works, it's not actually answering my question. Nonetheless, thank you for the clear input. Unfortunately the strategy isn't what I'm looking for given my architecture.

Comment: So instead you pick this one `RewriteRule ^item/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?id=$1/$2 [QSA,NC,L]` which is basically `RewriteRule  /?item/([\d]+)/([^/]+)/?$ product.php?ID=$1&description=$2 [L,QSA]` or `RewriteRule /?item/(.+?)/?$ product.php?ID=$1` is it not?  I don't care, but just saying baring some very minor differences ( which I asked for clarification on) the "solution" or "strategy" is the same, is it not.